# Passing blocks into partials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial-views

I would like to render partials into a view based on conditions. At first I have this view which renders well

```
<%= simple_form_for [@customer, @reading], :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f|             %>
<%= f.input :customer_id, :editable => false, :value => @customer.id %>
<%= f.input :date_of_reading, :as => :date %>
<%= render 'readings/single_phase', f: f %>
<% end %>
```

I now want to render partials into the view based on conditions. So i create a helper method in application.rb to do the conditional checking

```
module ApplicationHelper
 def render_readings_conditionally
  if @customer.phase_type == 'Single Phase'
  render :partial => 'readings/single_phase'
else
  render :partial => 'readings/three_phase'
end 
end
end
```

And in my view, I fix the method in there

```
<%= simple_form_for [@customer, @reading], :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do    |f| %>
<%= f.input :customer_id, :editable => false, :value => @customer.id %>
<%= f.input :date_of_reading, :as => :date %>
<%= render_readings_conditionally %>
 <% end %>
```

However, this will not work because I have not passed the block argument i had earlier on to my partials.

How can i pass it to my partials?

Comment: `def render_readings_conditionally(locals = {})` and pass a Hash of locals as parameters to your helper. Then render them like this: `render :partial => 'readings/three_phase', :locals => locals` could work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just rewrite it this way :

```
def render_readings_conditionally(form)
  if @customer.phase_type == 'Single Phase'
    render 'readings/single_phase', f: form
  else
    render 'readings/three_phase', f: form
  end 
end
```

And in your view :

```
<%= render_readings_conditionally(f) %>
```

Comment: For some reason it is still showing undefined local method f in the _single_phase.html view

Comment: It has actually worked, i removed the :partial bit and just did render 'readings/single_phase', f: form Wonder why it worked that way without having the :partial

Comment: My bad, I updated my answer. It is because you have to use `locals` to pass partial variable if you are using `render :partial` (see docs given in other answer)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at view partial locals :: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#passing-local-variables

You can pass any number of variables using locals.

The answer above is passing view locals, although they are being defined shorthand (not explicitly).

You could re-write the code like this, which makes it more clear which variables are being passed to your view partials. You can then access the "form_obj" object in your partial ::

```
  module ApplicationHelper
    def render_readings_conditionally
      if @customer.phase_type == 'Single Phase'
        render :partial => 'readings/single_phase', :locals => { :form_obj => form }
      else
        render :partial => 'readings/three_phase', :locals => { :form_obj => form }
      end

  end
```

Comment: I seem not to understand how to pass local variables in this case, can you please elaborate more for me?